# multi-output classification and regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

python scikit-learn にて RandomForestを用いたプログラムを実装中です．
n個の目的変数を分類，回帰で分析する際にn個モデルを作るのではなく
一つのモデルでn個の出力をするmulti-output classification and regression について
調べています．

scikit-learnのドキュメントの中で具体的にどういう仕組みで一つのモデルでn個の出力できるのか説明が見つけられなかったのですが
ご存知の方がいましたら教えてください．

よろしくお願いいたします．